# I want to split a string and want to put in the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

```
strPropertyEvents=20 Aug 2014-New Activity 1, 21 Aug 2014-gfdbfjdb ,21 Aug 2014-anubhav, 24 ug 2014-hjdf
```

Basically In  strPropertyEvents it is stored in the form of string but I want to split this string in such a manner that where there is a comma , it splits down there and the output is in a dropdown list as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#hiddenActivityDate').val('@strPropertyEvents');
alert($('#hiddenActivityDate').val());
var strList = hiddenActivityDate.split(',');
console.log(strList);
$.each(strList,function(index,val){
$("#ProgramList").append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
});
</script>
```

But the code is not working. Could you please help me out what is the mistake either in fiddle or anywhere.

Comment: "either in the fiddle" - I don't see a jsfiddle.

Comment: i want that it get corrrect either in fiddle or anywhere. Please help me out

Comment: yeah, post a link to jsfiddle which demonstrates the problem

Comment: You're not assigning any value to your `hiddenActivityDate` variable.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: I'm not sure but that might be resolved to a dom element `#hiddenActivityDate`. MSIE used to do that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No it didn't. It did allow `document.hiddenActivityDate` at some point, if memory serves.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: "IE made the situation worse by also adding named elements as properties of the window object.", http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/125816

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Obviously my memory didn't serve me very well :-) Apologies, should've done my homework.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: chrome does that even now!

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the definition of **hiddenActivityDate**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#hiddenActivityDate').val('@strPropertyEvents');
var hiddenActivityDate = $('#hiddenActivityDate').val();
var strList = hiddenActivityDate.split(',');
console.log(strList);
$.each(strList,function(index,val){
  $("#ProgramList").append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure where you get the string from, but I've added a working example where the string is declared at the top, as well as in a hidden input field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var strPropertyEvents="20 Aug 2014-New Activity 1, 21 Aug 2014-gfdbfjdb ,21 Aug 2014-anubhav, 24 ug 2014-hjdf";
    $('#hiddenActivityDate').val(strPropertyEvents);
    var strList = strPropertyEvents.split(',');
    console.log(strList);
    $.each(strList,function(index,val){
        $("#ProgramList").append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
    });
});
</script>


<input id="hiddenActivityDate" type="hidden" />

<select id="ProgramList"></select>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxqe2Lx8/2/)